# Machine Learning - Comparing Two Vectors

Tags: machine-learning, similarity, cosine-similarity

Is there a way to compare two vectors that do not follow any ordering semantics among its elements, by using any ML algorithm?

Example - Compare (1,3,5) vs (9,7,5) and arrive at some result, and then use that result to check how close/far away they are. And then, when I see (2,6,4), determine whether it is closer to (1,3,5) or to (9,7,5) in terms of any similarity notion taking into account each element?

While I can use my own custom algorithms, I am trying to check if there's any known, standard or established ML algorithm for this kind of use case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - cosine similarity